# How do I bind two date fields in my model to different date formats in Spring?

Tags: spring, date, data-binding, date-format

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I have a model with two java.util.Date fields …

```
public class MyModel
{
    ...
        private java.util.Date startDate;
        private java.util.Date meetingTime;
```

How do I set up a binder such that each field is converted against different date formats?  Currently I have

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat1);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
```

but this won't work because I want each field to be converted using different formats.  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of init binder you can use `@DateTimeFormat`

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private java.util.Date startDate;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd MMM yyyy")
private java.util.Date meetingTime;
```

If you use Spring older than 3.2, you might need to include joda-time on classpath